# Function in ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to learn Ajax/JavaScript and I can not seem to get my search to work. It is meant to return partial names but returns nothing at all

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getName(value) {
        $.post("searchbar.php", {partialName:value},function(data))
            $("#results").html(data);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="getName(this.value)"/>
    <br>
    <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
<?php
include "header.php";

$partialName = $_POST['partialName'];

$name = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM grpgusers WHERE username LIKE '%$partialName%'");
while($names = mysql_fetch_array($name)){
    echo "<div>".$names['username']."</div>";
}

?>
```

could some one please help me out on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Console is showing getName is not defined

Comment: Try to:
$(document input).on('change', '[type="text"]', function(){
 //your function where you can call $(this).val});
Try not to use inline declared events.
P.S. In future also try to send ajax on input change after some time (0.7 second after last keyup) less queries to DBMC - better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing braces, change to:

```
function getName(value) {
    $.post("searchbar.php", {partialName:value},function(data) {
        $("#results").html(data);
    });
}
```

Plus, missing a quote in

```
jquery.min.js ></script>
             ^ right there
```

change that to `jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: try removing all the ajax code and do a simple alert("test"); inside your getName() function..! and add double quote to script tag src..!

Comment: do you have double quote for closing the script tag that includes jquery library..?

Comment: @DemoUser Along with your answer, OP is missing a quote in `jquery.min.js></script>` OP needs to change it to `jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Missing closing double quote in `<script>` tag and closing brace for `$.post()` function :

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getName(value) {
        $.post("searchbar.php", {partialName: value}, function (data) {
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="getName(this.value)"/>
    <br>
    <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not double quote the link to the js libary
thanks

Comment: Not just that, but what the other answer pointed out. You should be accepting that answer, since it originally pointed out the missing braces. The quotes was *gravy*.